Constrain header in an X/Y-scrollable page to viewport width minus scrollbar
I'm attempting to have a header/body page with margins/padding, and a padded border around the body content, that constrains the width of the header to the viewport width minus scrollbar, irrespective of how wide the content below it expands horizontally.
The scrollbars for this page should affect the header position just as if it were full-width, i.e. it should not be fixed in place, and the scrollbars should not be positioned on, or affect only, the content below.
The best so far (with thanks to Cédric below) is max-width: calc(100% - 2.5rem) on the header element where 2.5rem is the twice the spacing amount I wanted to apply. This, however, constrains the bordered content area, which doesn't expand with the large content.
Note that this is not simply the same as "how can I make something the width minus scrollbars," as I have a feeling there must be some combination of CSS that will permit the lower section to expand but the top one not.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  margin: 1.25rem;
  width: calc(100% - 2.5rem);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.content {
  margin: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 3000px;
  margin: 1.25rem;
}
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>




You can set your width = 100% - (left and right margin).
It works because the page width is reduced when a scroll bar is added.


:root {
  --mx: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  margin: 0 var(--mx);
  width: calc(100% - 2 * var(--mx));
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 5000px;
  background-color: pink;
}
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>




Interestingly, that works fine except that my content is a div with some padding, and the large actual content inside that. When you apply some padding and border to .content above, and create another div inside that has the huge size, the .content doesn't expand to include that inner large element.

It would be interesting to add a snippet representing your problem. Here I set a fixed width to the content for the example, if you add a longer content inside, it will indeed overflow.

I've updated my original post to reflect your answer of 100%, and also the border and padding on the content. That does somewhat change the question, so apologies for that.

It probably should have been a new question indeed because the post doesn't make much sense now. I think you want to set width:fit-content to .content (or maybe overflow-x:scroll; to avoid your content to overflow).
